# Webauthn working on Mac but not on Safari iOS

Tags: javascript, html, webauthn

For my project, I'm interesting using webauthn (FaceID TouchID) for security. After digging on Google and Github, I can buil simple webauthn. But, due to lack of javascript and authentication technology, i don;t understand why this code can running well on Mac (computer) but not on Safari iOS (iPhone).

Here the code:

```
<script>
    function printHex(msg, buf) {
        if (ArrayBuffer.isView(buf) && buf.buffer instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
            buf = buf.buffer;
        }
        var response = '';

        if ((typeof msg != "string") ||
            (typeof buf != "object")) {
            return "Bad args to printHex";
        }
        if (!(buf instanceof ArrayBuffer)) {
            return "Attempted printHex with non-ArrayBuffer:", buf;
        }

        var arr = new Uint8Array(buf);
        var len = buf.byteLength;
        var i;
        var str = "";
        response += msg, `(${buf.byteLength} bytes)`;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            var hexch = arr[i].toString(16);
            hexch = (hexch.length == 1) ? ("0" + hexch) : hexch;
            str += hexch.toUpperCase() + " ";
            if (i && !((i + 1) % 16)) {
                response += str;
                str = "";
            }
        }

        if ((i) % 16) {
            response += str;
        }
        return response;
    }

    var createCredentialDefaultArgs = {
        publicKey: {

            rp: {
                name: "Acme",
                icon: "https://www.w3.org/StyleSheets/TR/2016/logos/W3C"
            },

            user: {
                id: new Uint8Array(16),
                name: "test@test.com",
                displayName: "test"
            },

            pubKeyCredParams: [{
                type: "public-key",
                alg: -7,
                transports: "internal",
            }],

            attestation: "direct",

            timeout: 60000,

            challenge: new Uint8Array([
                0x8C, 0x0A, 0x26, 0xFF, 0x22, 0x91, 0xC1, 0xE9, 0xB9, 0x4E, 0x2E, 0x17, 0x1A, 0x98, 0x6A, 0x73,
                0x71, 0x9D, 0x43, 0x48, 0xD5, 0xA7, 0x6A, 0x15, 0x7E, 0x38, 0x94, 0x52, 0x77, 0x97, 0x0F, 0xEF,
                0x79, 0x50, 0x68, 0x71, 0xDA, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xB9, 0x94, 0xC3, 0xC2, 0x15, 0x67, 0x65, 0x26, 0x22,
                0xE3, 0xF3, 0xAB, 0x3B, 0x78, 0x2E, 0xD5, 0x6F, 0x81, 0x26, 0xE2, 0xA6, 0x01, 0x7D, 0x74, 0x50
            ]).buffer
        }
    };

    var getCredentialDefaultArgs = {
        publicKey: {
            timeout: 60000,
            // allowCredentials: [newCredential]
            challenge: new Uint8Array([
                0x8C, 0x0A, 0x26, 0xFF, 0x22, 0x91, 0xC1, 0xE9, 0xB9, 0x4E, 0x2E, 0x17, 0x1A, 0x98, 0x6A, 0x73,
                0x71, 0x9D, 0x43, 0x48, 0xD5, 0xA7, 0x6A, 0x15, 0x7E, 0x38, 0x94, 0x52, 0x77, 0x97, 0x0F, 0xEF,
                0x79, 0x50, 0x68, 0x71, 0xDA, 0xEE, 0xEE, 0xB9, 0x94, 0xC3, 0xC2, 0x15, 0x67, 0x65, 0x26, 0x22,
                0xE3, 0xF3, 0xAB, 0x3B, 0x78, 0x2E, 0xD5, 0x6F, 0x81, 0x26, 0xE2, 0xA6, 0x01, 0x7D, 0x74, 0x50
            ]).buffer
        },
    };

    ((async function () {
        var cred = await navigator.credentials.create(createCredentialDefaultArgs);
        console.log("NEW CREDENTIAL", cred);
        document.getElementById("rawId").innerHTML = printHex("rawId: ", cred.rawId);

        document.getElementById("attestationObject").innerHTML = printHex("attestationObject: ", cred.response.attestationObject);
        document.getElementById("clientDataJSON").innerHTML = printHex("clientDataJSON: ", cred.response.clientDataJSON);

        var idList = [{
            id: cred.rawId,
            transports: ["internal"],
            type: "public-key"
        }];
        getCredentialDefaultArgs.publicKey.allowCredentials = idList;
        var assertion = await navigator.credentials.get(getCredentialDefaultArgs);
        console.log("ASSERTION", assertion);
        document.getElementById("assertion").innerHTML = assertion;
        document.getElementById("clientDataJSON").innerHTML = printHex("clientDataJSON", assertion.response.clientDataJSON);
        document.getElementById("authenticatorData").innerHTML = printHex("authenticatorData", assertion.response.authenticatorData);
        document.getElementById("signature").innerHTML = printHex("signature", assertion.response.signature);
        document.getElementById("userHandle").innerHTML = printHex("userHandle", assertion.response.userHandle);
    })())
        .then(() => console.log("done"))
        .catch((err) => console.log("ERROR:", err));

</script>

<div id="rawId"></div>
<div id="attestationObject"></div>
<div id="clientDataJSON"></div>

<div id="assertion"></div>
<div id="clientDataJSON"></div>
<div id="authenticatorData"></div>
<div id="signature"></div>
<div id="userHandle"></div>
```

Comment: Which version of iOS?

Comment: @connexo Safari on iOS 15.0

Comment: In what way does it fail? Anything logged to the console etc?

Comment: @mackie on Safari iOS, the script just blank. Noting happened. In Mac, it's running well.

Comment: Try changing it so that the `err` is displayed on the page somehow inside tghe catch function. My gut feel is that the `attestation` param may be the problem here but we need to see that error to confirm.